# Can you programmatically change session time out in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, timeout

Can it be done or the only way is to configure it on IIS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You edit generally the Global.asax file's Session_Start method and set [Session.TimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx) to whatever you want.  You can do this anywhere else in your code too.

Comment: what happens when it differs with the value set in IIS?

Comment: I believe you Web.Config/Program/Machine.Config file overrides IIS's default setting.  Edit: godammit, you would think MS would put that in the HttpSessionState.TimeOut docs.

Comment: Well... now I'm not sure.  I guess you can try it out yourself ;)  And usually MSDN is so good at keeping track of this sort of thing, so I'm flip-flopping back to my original answer for now...

Comment: As stated by `balexandre`, Manually setting `Session.Timeout` does not overwrite the IIS default of 20 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

you can, **but it will not override** the IIS settings (by default 20 minutos) if you are in a Shared Hosted environment.

what I do is apply the use of **SQL Sessions**, it will turn the web application a little more slow, but you have total control of the sessions and if you update something to the application and the Compiler needs to re-compile the resources/classes again, the user will **not be logged out**.

Sessions will be kept in a special table of the SQL database.

Comment: I can give you a DiscountASP.NET answer received in 26 09 2006:
--
Dear Costumer,
"... As for the session, our servers use 20 minutes of session timeout, anything beyond that, they will need sql session    

DiscountASP.NET
The power of ASP.NET for less

Comment: that is set in machine.config file that is in the server and you can flag it to be not override by web.config for example.

Comment: received from Brinkster at 24 08 2006 
--
Hello,
I am sorry, the session timeout is set to 20 minutes. This cannot be
changed on our shared hosting servers.




Thank you,

Douglas
Technical Support Representative
Brinkster Communications Corporation
www.Brinkster.com

Answer (score 1):

If your in a hosted environment and your not allowed to override IIS default session timeout (as others have mentioned in the comments), you can trick IIS into keeping the session alive for longer by using an iframe that refreshes the session over and over (kind of like a keep alive ping) for whatever interval of time you need. I had this situation and used this approach

[ASP.NET Push Redirect on Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484964/asp-net-push-redirect-on-session-timeout/5863952#5863952)