# ASP.NET Push Redirect on Session Timeout

Tags: asp.net, redirect, session-timeout, server-push

I'm looking for a tutorial, blog entry, or some help on the technique behind websites that automatically push users (ie without a postback) when the session expires.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "push users?"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Usually, you set the session timeout, and you can additionally add a page header to automatically redirect the current page to a page where you clear the session right before the session timeout.

From http://aspalliance.com/1621_Implementing_a_Session_Timeout_Page_in_ASPNET.2

```
namespace SessionExpirePage
{
    public partial class Secure : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        public int SessionLengthMinutes
        {
            get { return Session.Timeout; }
        }
        public string SessionExpireDestinationUrl
        {
            get { return "/SessionExpired.aspx"; }
        }
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            this.PageHead.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
                String.Format("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='{0};url={1}'>", 
                SessionLengthMinutes*60, SessionExpireDestinationUrl)));
        }
    }
}
```

The SessionExpireDestinationUrl should link to a page where you clear the session and any other user data.

When the refresh header expires, it will automatically redirect them to that page.

Answer (score 11):

You can't really "push" a client from your website.  Your site will respond to requests from the client, but that's really it.

What this means is that you need to write something client-side (Javascript) that will determine when the user has timed out, probably by comparing the current time with the most recent time they have in a site cookie (which you update with the current time each time the user visits a page on your site), and then redirect if the difference is greater than a certain amount.

(I note that some people are advocating just creating a script that will forward the user after a certain amount of time on a page.  This will work in the simple case, but if the user has two windows open on the site, and is using one window a lot, and the other window not-so-much, the not-so-much one will suddenly redirect the user to the forwarding page, even though the user has been on the site constantly.  Additionally, it's not really in sync with any session keeping you're doing on the server side.  On the other hand, it's certainly easier to code, and if that's good enough, then great!)

Answer (score 7):

In the <HEAD> section, use a META refresh tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0000; URL=target_page.html">
```

where 0000 is your session timeout in seconds, and target_page.html the address of the page to be redirected to.

Comment: You know what? I love you for that one :)
Plain, simple and just working, perfect for a beginner in asp.net like me :)

Answer (score 4):

### Using Custom Page class and Javascript also we can achieve it.

Create a custom pagebase class and write the common functionality codes into this class. Through this class, we can share the common functions to other web pages. In this class we need inherit the *System.Web.UI.Page* class. Place the below code into Pagebase class

***PageBase.cs***

```
namespace AutoRedirect
{
    public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            AutoRedirect();
        }

        public void AutoRedirect()
        {
            int int_MilliSecondsTimeOut = (this.Session.Timeout * 60000);
            string str_Script = @"
               <script type='text/javascript'> 
                   intervalset = window.setInterval('Redirect()'," +
                       int_MilliSecondsTimeOut.ToString() + @");
                   function Redirect()
                   {
                       window.location.href='/login.aspx'; 
                   }
               </script>";

           ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Redirect", str_Script);
        }
    }
}
```

Above *AutoRedirect function* will be used to redirect the login page when session expires, by using *javascript window.setInterval*, This window.setInterval executes a javascript function repeatedly with specific time delay. Here we are configuring the time delay as session timeout value. Once it’s reached the session expiration time then automatically executes the Redirect function and control transfer to login page.

***OriginalPage.aspx.cs***

```
namespace appStore
{
    public partial class OriginalPage: Basepage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }     
    }
}
```

***OriginalPage.aspx***

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="OriginalPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutoRedirect.OriginalPage" %>
```

***Web.config***

```
<system.web>    
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="3"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Note:
The advantage of using Javascript is you could show custom message in alert box before location.href which will make perfect sense to user.
In case if you don't want to use Javascript you could choose meta redirection also

```
public void AutoRedirect()
{
    this.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
        String.Format("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='{0};url={1}'>",
            this.Session.Timeout * 60, "login.aspx")));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just copy and paste this code snippet in your Web.Config file :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="29" />
</authentication>

<sessionState timeout="30" mode="InProc" cookieless="false" />
```

You can put this line to your Site.Master :

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", 
                      Convert.ToString((Session.Timeout * 60)) + 
                      ";URL=~/Login.aspx");
```

Comment: Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", Convert.ToString((Session.Timeout * 60)) + ";URL=" & System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);

Answer (score 2):

I'm using MVC3 ASp.net as beginner, I tried many solution to solve my session problem ( since i'm using Session variable in my code, and after timeout i didn't have session values while i'm keep using it And I just find that my problem was in config file. the timeout between Authentication and sessionState should be so close. so they Killed (empty) at the same time // add timeout 1 and 2 for testing.. it's should be at least 29 and 30

I used others way it's work too :

Starting from :

```
    protected void Session_Start(object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Session != null)
        {
            if (Context.Session.IsNewSession)//|| Context.Session.Count==0)
            {
                string sCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != sCookieHeader) && (sCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    //if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                     FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                     Response.Redirect("/Account/LogOn");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //Code that runs when a session ends. 
     //Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode 
     //is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer
      //or SQLServer, the event is not raised. 
        Session.Clear();          
    }
```

And :

```
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check if session is supported
        if (ctx.Session != null)
        {

            // check if a new session id was generated
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                // have timed out
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Home/LogOn");
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And even worked with Ajax to solve session issuse:

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Session.Count == 0 || Session["CouncilID"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("/Account/LogOn");

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() && (!Request.IsAuthenticated || User == null))
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (!httpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {//validate http request.
                if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated
                    || httpContext.Session["User"] == null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/?returnurl=" + httpContext.Request.Url.ToString());
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        // put whatever data you want which will be sent
                        // to the client
                        message = "sorry, but you were logged out"
                    },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it can't be done. The session timeout only occurs on the server side and you won't detect this until the user performs some kind of post back action.

However, what you CAN do is to inject some HTML or JavaScript header code that will automatically push the user to a logout page in the same timeframe as your session timeout. This doesn't guarantee a perfect synch, and you may run into issues if your user is doing some time intensive items and you are not resetting the clock.

I typically add this code to my Page_Load events to accomplish this.

```
' Register Javascript timeout event to redirect to the login page after inactivity
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "TimeoutScript", _
                                              "setTimeout(""top.location.href = 'Login.aspx'""," & _
                                               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SessionTimeoutMilliseconds") & ");", True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need to use `[Authorize]` over controller class or even Action in specific.

```
[Authorize]
public class MailController : Controller
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you use the following Logon controller, it will send you to the requested URL before logon:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    //return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this gets tricky for AJAX requests as Zhaph - Ben Duguid pointed out. Here was my solution to make this work with AJAX (using Telerik web controls but they are built using ASP.NET AJAX toolkit I believe).

In a nutshell, I rolled my own sliding expiration session type thing.

In my Site.Master, I am updating a session variable on EVERY postback (postback or AJAX request because AJAX requests still kick off the Page_Load event):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (this.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                this.pnlSessionKeepAlive.Visible = true;
            else
                this.pnlSessionKeepAlive.Visible = false;
        }

        if (this.Session["SessionStartDateTime"] != null)
            this.Session["SessionStartDateTime"] = DateTime.Now;
        else
            this.Session.Add("SessionStartDateTime", DateTime.Now);
    }
```

Then in my markup for my site.master, I included an iframe with a ASPX page I use "behind the scenes" to check and see if my custom sliding expiration has expired:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSessionKeepAlive" Visible="false">
 <iframe id="frame1" runat="server" src="../SessionExpire.aspx" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" / >
 </asp:Panel>
```

Now in my SessionExpire.aspx page, I just refresh the page every so often and check if the timestamp has lapsed and if so, I redirect to my logout.aspx page that then determines which login page to send the user back to:

```
public partial class SessionExpire : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* We have to do all of this because we need to redirect to 2 different login pages. The default .NET
         * implementation does not allow us to specify which page to redirect expired sessions, its a fixed value.
         */
        if (this.Session["SessionStartDateTime"] != null)
        {
            DateTime StartTime = new DateTime();
            bool IsValid = DateTime.TryParse(this.Session["SessionStartDateTime"].ToString(), out StartTime);
            if (IsValid)
            {
                int MaxSessionTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionKeepAliveMins"]);
                IsValid = (DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartTime).TotalMinutes < MaxSessionTimeout);
            }

            // either their session expired or their sliding session timeout has expired. Now log them out and redirect to the correct
            // login page.
            if (!IsValid)
                this.Logout();
        }
        else
            this.Logout();

        // check every 60 seconds to see if the session has expired yet.
        Response.AddHeader("Refresh", Convert.ToString(60));
    }

    private void Logout()
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "TimeoutScript",
                    "setTimeout(\"top.location.href = '../Public/Logout.aspx'\",\"1000\");", true);
    }
}
```

Many thanks to the people above who posted info, this lead me to my solution and hope it helps others.