# log out a user on session expiration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, forms-authentication

What is the best way to force a user to login again if the session expires. I am using forms authentication. Also the solution needs to work even if user has multiple tabs opened in the browser.

Answer (score 5):

This happens automatically. Once the session is expired, the next page the user requests that requires authentication should redirect to the login page. If you mean that you want the page no longer displayed if left sitting for too long, there are a couple of approaches.

1. Add a [META REFRESH tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484964/asp-net-push-redirect-on-session-timeout) to every page header. The refresh time
   should be close or equal to the session timeout. Note that if you
   make AJAX calls, the refresh tag does not reset the timer to zero.
2. Use the [Javascript setTimeout function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20settimeout%20session%20timeout) to redirect just before the
   session timeout.