# How to Automatically Redirect if Session Expires? ASP.Net (From SessionTimeout.aspx to Timeout.aspx)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used Global.asax and this two codes give me error after session has timeout, like:
 'Response is not available in this context.' - if I used Response.Redirect
 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' - if I used HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect

**Global.asax**

```
 protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("timeout.aspx");
            Response.Redirect("~/timeout.aspx");
        }
```

and this is on my Web.Config

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="../error_page/" mode="Off"/>
    <sessionState timeout="1" cookieless="false" mode="InProc" ></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**SessionTimeout.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["CustomSessionId"] = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
```

Do you guys have any solutions, suggestion especially snippets to make this work out? I am just an entry level programmer, not an advance one.

Comment: Check this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484964/asp-net-push-redirect-on-session-timeout. Also check `Session.IsNewSession`, since `Session_End` event not attached to any `Request` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless protocol that is initiated by the client. So you can't to use Session expiration to allow the page to automatically `Redirect` to the page, but you can try to use *Js* `setInterval` function set timeout time the value same as `Sesssion.TimeOut` to simulate.

So you can render a *JS* by `DoRedirect` method. The `DoRedirect` method require a parameter your Redirect page name.

`window.setInterval` require *MilliSeconds* time to set invoke time, so you need to You need to multiply 60000 by `Session.Timeout`.

**SessionTimeout.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    DoRedirect("timeout.aspx");
}

public void DoRedirect(string page)
{
    int TimeOut = (this.Session.Timeout * 60000);
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    sb.AppendLine("window.setInterval('Redirect()'," +TimeOut.ToString() + @"); ");
    sb.AppendLine(" function Redirect(){ ");
    sb.AppendLine("window.location.href='/" + page + @"';");
    sb.AppendLine("}");
    sb.AppendLine(" </script>");

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Redirect", sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do I add this to global.asax? Because when I did add this, on asax, this error shows up. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Yes you need to add `Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute` on global.asax, I edit my anwser:)

Comment: there is still an existing problem, although it redirects to timeout.aspx and doesn't ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS anymore, it doesn't wait on sessionstate timeout to be timed out.

Comment: To be precise, when I run the SessionTimeout.aspx, it redirects immediately on timeout.aspx

Comment: I see,Why don't you Redirect to `timeout.aspx` on `SessionTimeout.aspx.cs`  `Page_Load` directly, just like my edit2 answer

Comment: Still the same output, do you know a method where you can post on SessionTimeout.aspx without a button using session_end?